# How to sort dates of string?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting

I have an array of date as `2017-07-06,2017-06-07,2017-07-07`. I want to sort these dates in ascending order. So 2017-06-07 will come first. But it is not happening at all. I am using below code for this:

```
func sortDates(array:NSMutableArray)->[String]  {

        var strArray:[String] = []
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"// yyyy-MM-dd"
        var convertedArray: [Date] = []
        for dat in array {
            let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dat as! String)
            convertedArray.append(date!)
        }
        let arrDates = convertedArray.sorted(by: { $0.compare($1) == .orderedAscending })
        for value in arrDates {
            let formatter = DateFormatter()
            // initially set the format based on your datepicker date
            formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
            let myString = formatter.string(from: value)
            // convert your string to date
            let yourDate = formatter.date(from: myString)
            if yourDate != nil {
                //then again set the date format whhich type of output you need
                formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
                // again convert your date to string
                let myStringafd = formatter.string(from: yourDate!)
                strArray.append(myStringafd)
            }
        }
        return strArray
    }
```

Please guide me where I am doing wrong ?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "it is not happening"? Explain what your code is doing. I do not want to read through code to try to understand it. and determine what it is doing wrong.

Comment: Use `yyyy-MM-dd`, not with `mm` The lowercase one is for minutes (see the doc http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

Comment: Apart from the identifier issue you can compare easier `$0 < $1`

Answer (score 2):

It is not necessary to convert these strings to Date type.  You can simply sort them as strings and they will come out in the right order.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an extension to convert the `string` to `date` and then just append all your `dates-objects` to an `array` and sort that `array`.

Extensions:

```
extension String {
    var toDate: Date {
        return Date.Formatter.customDate.date(from: self)!
    }
}

extension Date {
    struct Formatter {
        static let customDate: DateFormatter = {
            let formatter = DateFormatter()
            formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
            formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
            return formatter
        }()
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let d1 = "2017-01-01".toDate
let d2 = "2016-01-01".toDate
let d3 = "2018-01-01".toDate
let d4 = "2013-01-01".toDate

let convertedArray = [d1,d2, d3, d4]
let sorted = convertedArray.sorted() // note that the sort works on a string too.
print(sorted)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
extension String  {

func date(format: String) -> Date? {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = format
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: self)
    return date
}

}
extension Date {
func string(format: String) -> String {
    let dateFormatterPrint = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatterPrint.dateFormat = format
    return dateFormatterPrint.string(from: self) as String
}
}
var datesSting = ["2017-07-06","2017-08-07","2017-07-07"]

let soteddates  = datesSting.map { (obj) -> Date in
    return obj.date(format: "yyyy-MM-DD")!
}

let sorteedStings = soteddates.sorted { (obj1, obj2) -> Bool in
    return obj1.compare(obj2) == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending
}.map { (obj) -> String in
   return obj.string(format:  "yyyy-MM-DD")
}

print(sorteedStings)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is mine code:

```
   let arrCurrentDate = [“2017-07-06”, “2017-06-07", “2017-07-07”]
   var arrConverted: [Date] = []

   let dateFrmt = DateFormatter()
   dateFrmt.dateFormat = “yyyy-MM-dd”

   for dateCurrent in arrCurrentDate {
     let date = dateFrmt.date(from: dateCurrent)
     arrConverted.append(date!)
   }       
   arrConverted.sort(by: {$0.compare($1) == .orderedAscending})       
   arrConverted.sorted(by: {$0.timeIntervalSince1970 < $1.timeIntervalSince1970})

   print(arrConverted)
```

You can change your order also:

**.orderedAscending
.orderedSame
.orderedDescending**